# Create SidekiqWorkers on a server by receiving information from another server

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, jrubyonrails

Sorry If my title didn't made any sense, but my problem is that, I have one application which is hosted on a server, the application uses a database which is hosted on the same server, also the same server is using sidekiq to process a lot of queues.

One problem, is that a lot of memory is used, and everything works very slow, and even if I have a 8 core processor, I can't take advantage of it when processing queues because the application was developed on MRI and is using Unicorn.

I was thinking at moving all the part which is used to process the queues on a different server, there install Puma, and jRuby and process the queues in there(this process should be a lot faster by taking advantage of multiple cores.

All the data processed by sidekiq, is coming from a Database and is stored in a Database(currently is the same database from where it takes the info and where is storing the data). Most of the sidekiq workers are receiving some information, and are using that information to get other informations so they need to connect to the same db as the app.

What will be a good solution, to serve the same database to 2 different applications?
And is it a good idea to have another server with Puma and jRuby installed for sidekiq only(maybe other things in the future)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with MRI and Unicorn you can take advantage of multiple cores: Just start unicorn multiple times or use the [clustered mode](https://github.com/puma/puma#clustered-mode) provided by Puma. Same for Sidekiq. No need to switch to JRuby right away.

Accessing the database from multiple application is no problem. But do yourself a favor and use a dedicated database server. Makes added more application servers way easier.